# SpringBoot configuration with pure Hibernate ORM without JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm new to SpringBoot development and I want to add **Hibernate ORM framework** to my SpringBoot project. I know

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

this dependency gives that capability but it's not supporting for every Hibernate features in pure Hibernate framework.

**Example:**

```
session.createNativeQuery(query).addEntity(LectureSchedule.class).list();
```

is there any way to configure Hibernate framework for SpringBoot applications not via JPA dependency and autowire SessionFactory so I can perform basic hibernate coding after that without using JPA methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use the spring starter pom file, you can add the hibernate dependencies one by one - depending on your needs.

The minimums are the `hibernate-core` package and `spring-orm`.

This [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring) describes how to do it step by step.

Comment: Thanks for the advice it was very helpful.